# getApplicationContext() throws an exception when used

Tags: android, exception, android-context

I've specified a class, based on another one in an existing Android project. The addRow() method is supposed to dynamically add rows to a table.
When creating a new TextView to add to my row and also when creating that row, I'm supposed to specify the "context". The current way, trying "getApplicationContext()" throws a NullPointerException.
So where am I supposed to get that context from?

```
public class DistanceTableView extends ContactListActivity
{
    public void addRow(LocationMessage locationMsg){
        View messageView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage, null);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)messageView.findViewById(R.id.distanceTable);

        TextView senderNameTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        senderNameTextView.setText(locationMsg.getSenderName());

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tr.addView(distanceTextView);
        table.addView(tr);

        rows.addFirst(messageView);
    }
}
```

The class that my view is extending:

```
public class ContactListActivity extends MapActivity implements
        ConnectionListener {}
```

Comment: How are you using DistanceTableView? Also, it might help if we see how ContactListActivity is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to pass the context to the constructor of your class.

Comment: That helped. I thought the context would always be the same when I'm extending that class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);`

Comment: That also throws an exception