# Should I use getApplicationContext or Activity.this in a long running AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have a long running Async Task that sends some data to my server and then stops. The whole process may involve a few requests and response. I have to read data from database, send it and handle the response and update my database accordingly. I am using content providers to read and update data from database.

Now to use the Content Provider, I have to call the `getContentResolver()` method on context. So I am wondering whether I have to use `getApplicationContext` or just pass the `Activity.this` to my methods.

I saw a few posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context) explaining the difference between the two and in most of them they advice us to not use `getApplicationContext` if possible. Although I do not want my `AsyncTask` to lose the context from `Activity.this` when the `Activity` is destroyed or when orientation changes. So I am wondering if I can use `getApplicationContext` in my case or will using `Activity.this` fit my requirement.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There is a reason to use each of the options.

When you are using the context in order to modify the UI, you **should** use the Activity context, since in some cases using the application context might cause an exception ([as described here](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2009/12/context.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851394/getapplicationcontext-throws-an-exception-when-used)). Such as in the following case:

```
TextView senderNameTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

When you are using the context in cross-activity usage, you should not bind the Activity context to the action, since then even if the activity is destroyed, it will not be garbage-collected, as it is still referenced from the running task. In those cases, you should use the Application context. See [the article in Android Developer's site](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) (written by [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy)) for even more details.

If you are only using the context to call `getContentResolver`, you should use the Application context.

Comment: Thanks for the `as described here` .