# Unable to resume activity - Runtime exception

Tags: android, opencv

```
     @Override
            public void onResume()
            {
                super.onResume();
                OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_7, this, mLoaderCallback);
            }

            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

            }

        private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
                @Override
                public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                    switch (status) {
                        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                        {

                            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully...................");
                        }
  } 
                    default:
                    {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    } break;
                }
            }
        };
```

here is my log

> 0java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.lowfreq/com.example.lowfreq.Sample}:
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@41b9aca8 is not valid; is your activity
>   running? 1    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
>   2 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
>   3 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   4 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
>   5 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
>   6 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 7   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 8 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 9   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 11   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   12    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>   13    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 14Caused by:
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@41b9aca8 is not valid; is your activity
>   running? 15   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:561) 16   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
>   17    at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   18    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287) 19  at
>   org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback.onPackageInstall(BaseLoaderCallback.java:110)
>   20    at
>   org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.InstallService(AsyncServiceHelper.java:116)
>   21    at
>   org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV(AsyncServiceHelper.java:32)
>   22    at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.java:60)
>   23    at com.example.lowfreq.Sample.onResume(Sample.java:189) 24  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1194)
>   25    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5315) 26    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804)

Is there any mistake in the way OPEN CV is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` in `OpenCVLoader.initAsync(..)`.

Reason: [Should I use getApplicationContext or Activity.this in a long running AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122627/should-i-use-getapplicationcontext-or-activity-this-in-a-long-running-asynctask)

Comment: Tried it, still get the same exception

Comment: super.onManagerConnected(status) be called before the switch case instead of having it in default case.