# code Error in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

I think I is just a small mistake but I cant find it. In the following code my whole `@Override` method is marked as "false".

```js
        inputBill.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        inputBill.setText(dayOfMonth + "." + monthOfYear + "." + year);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Error:(162, 61) error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnFocusChangeListener> cannot be converted to Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use instance of `View.OnFocusChangeListener` to show dialog. For Alerts you always need Activity context, So you need to use current activity instance there.

---

Problem is

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(**this**, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

use

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(ACTIVITY_NAME.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

Comment: "You can accept this answer in 3 minutes" be patient :P

Answer (score 1):

### Edited

You can use **getContext()**

```
 DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
```

Comment: AFAIK, `getApplicationContext()` is not suitable here.

Comment: getApplicationContext().this ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122627/should-i-use-getapplicationcontext-or-activity-this-in-a-long-running-asynctask

Comment: This is inside a Fragment. I use `getContext()`now

Comment: Generally, for in-activity UI stuff, application context is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

**As a side note to @Pankaj Kumar's answer:**

Whenever you instantiate an anonymous class, inside that class `this` refers to the instantiating class not your main class.

```
public class MainClass{
    public method(){
        new AnotherClass(){
            public someMethod(){
                Object o1 = this;
                Object o2 = MainClass.this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example:

- `o1`: Points to current instance of `AnotherClass`.
- `o2`: Points to current instance of `MainClass`.