# Error in making a bookmark using sharedPrefs

Tags: android

Guys can you help me figure out what is the error in my activity,

is it a null pointer exception or onclick error?

i used this code for bookmarking a text which is done by having sharedpreferences.

hoping for your help.

Here's the logcat:

```
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at j.app.biblia.BookmarksActivity$1.onClick(BookmarksActivity.java:87)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-12 07:19:29.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the activity:

```
public class BookmarksActivity extends Activity
{
    private TextView mEmptyText;
    private LinearLayout mBookmarkLayout;

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        mEmptyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_textview);
        mBookmarkLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_insert_point);

        getAllKeys();
    }

    private void getAllKeys()
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("bookmarks", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String,?> keys = sp.getAll();

        int count = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet())
        {
            String value = entry.getValue().toString();
            System.out.println("value = "+value);
            String delimiter = ",";
            String[] values_array = value.split(delimiter);
            addBookmark(values_array);
            count++; //keep track of the number of bookmarks
        }

        //if there are no bookmarks, display a text view saying so.  Otherwise, make the text view go away
        if (count == 0)
        {
            mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mEmptyText.setText(getString(R.string.no_bookmarks));
        }
        else
            mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    private void addBookmark(String[] values_array)
    {       
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.single_bookmark, null);

        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_text);
        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_button);

        text.setText(values_array[1]);

        final String myClass = values_array[0];
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Class<?> cl = null;
                try {
                    cl = Class.forName(myClass);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        // insert into main view
        mBookmarkLayout.addView(v, 0, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        System.out.println("view added");
    }
}
```

thanks guys!

Comment: Which line is the 87th ?

Comment: if you dont mind, but my adt doesnt have line numbers, and if there is, how to do that? thanks!

Comment: i count it manually and it is around this lines:

Comment: final String myClass = values_array[0];
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       Class<?> cl = null;
       try {
           cl = Class.forName(myClass);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);
       startActivity(myIntent);
   }

Comment: Well, you need to be more specific. The log show that it happens in the onClick method : `at j.app.biblia.BookmarksActivity$1.onClick(BookmarksActivity.java:87)` but you need to give us the precise line.

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, cl);

Comment: So, `cl` must be null.

Comment: how could i fix that?

Comment: Be sure that `myClass` has the proper value, because at the moment it can't load the class.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater li= LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

instead of

`LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

This is generally happen due to memory leaking. For more on [Memory leak](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: you can get more on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851394/getapplicationcontext-throws-an-exception-when-used